# Button and ToggleButton won't align at same height

Tags: android, button, android-layout

I'm having troubles designing the menu of an application with XML. What I want to do is to have both `ToggleButton` and `Button` at same height, but the `Button` doesn't appear aligned. It's like if it had something invisible below it that makes it appear a little higher.

I've been looking for info, but I found nothing

Here's the code I wrote on the main.xml:

```
(...)    
    <TextView
        android:text="Option1:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_option1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="100sp"
        android:height="50sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_option1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50sp"
        android:text="See" 
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you please provide us a screenshot? Just post the image URL in the question and I will post the image.

Comment: change `ToggleButton`'s height as `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: Thank you Adil Soomro, changing to fill_parent works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_option1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="100sp"
    android:height="50sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_option1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:height="50sp"
    android:text="See" 
    android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With the layout_margins Carnal Suggested it works perfect! Isn't it weird that they're not aligned by default? PS: I'd Vote up, but i can't because I'm still below 15 in reputation. I'll do it when I'm able to!

Comment: It's ok mate, but there is an easier way actually. Instead of using android:layout_marginBottom and marginTop, try to use android:layout_height="fill_parent" on togglebutton, see if it works :)

Comment: Yees it does! I think that's the best way actually!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tbtnAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:height="48dp"
         />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/tbtnOther"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:height="50dp"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ToggleButton 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/toggle_option1" 
android:layout_width="70dp">
</ToggleButton>
    <Button 
android:id="@+id/button_option1"
 android:text="See" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="70dp">
</Button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't really do what we were looking for even if I add the horizontal Linear Layout; Button's still non-aligned with toggle